# Shouldn't the code print " 1 1" instead of "4 4"?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

According to §7.2/5 and §7.2/6 shouldn't the [code below](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4496d16bf4da56c1) print `1 1` instead of `4 4`?

```
#include <iostream>
enum A { a = (char)1, b, c };   //  underlying type is not fixed

int main() {
    std::cout << sizeof(a) << ' ' << sizeof(A) << '\n';
}
```

**Edit**

> From §7.2/5:
>
> If the underlying type is not fixed, the type of each enumerator is
>   the type of its initializing value:
>
> — If an initializer is specified for an enumerator, the initializing
>   value has the same type as the expression and the constant-expression
>   shall be an integral constant expression (5.19).

Comment: Neither clause states that the underlying type must be the smallest possible.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth See my Edit above

Comment: I think "Following the closing brace of an enum-specifier, each enumerator has the type of its enumeration." from §7.2/5 also applies to enumerations with non-fixed types. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc6897fa1bfab56f)

Comment: There's a difference between the type of (the initializing value of) an enumerator and the type of the enumeration. The underlying type of the enumeration is large enough to hold the values of all the enumerators.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you don't explicitly define the underlying type, then compiler is free to choose an integral type which fits the values. To set the underlying type in C++11 you can use this:

```
enum A : char { a = 1, b, c }; 
       ^^^^^^
```

Your way will not force the compiler to use `char` instead if `int`.

Answer (score 5):

This is implementation defined: the fact that all values of an `enum` fit in, say, a `uint8_t` does not force the compiler to pick a single-byte representation for the enumeration.

> The underlying type of an enumeration is an integral type that can represent all the enumerator values defined in the enumeration. **It is implementation-defined which integral type is used as the underlying type for an enumeration** except that the underlying type shall not be larger than int unless the value of an enumerator cannot fit in an int or `unsigned int`. (emphasis added)

In your case it appears that the compiler implementers choose an `int`, which takes four bytes on your platform - a perfectly valid choice.

Answer (score 4):

The clause you quote, 7.2/5, describes the types of the *enumerators*. But the enumerators only form part of the definition of the *enumeration*. The underlying type of the enumeration is large enough to hold the values all enumerators, subject to 7.2/6:

> It is implementation-defined which integral type is used as the underlying type except that the underlying type shall not be larger than `int` unless the value of an enumerator cannot fit in an `int` or `unsigned int`.

So it is guaranteed that your underlying type is no larger than `int` (since `int` can represent 0, 1 and 2). It is true that the type of your first enumerator is `char` inside the enum definition, but all actual enum values are of type `A`. To actually control the underlying type, use the *enum-base* syntax (e.g. `enum A : char`), and to query it you can use the `std::underlying_type` trait.

If you actually would like to see the effect of the enumerator's type in the definition, you can try something like this:

```
enum Foo { a = '\010', b = sizeof(a) };

std::cout << typeid(b).name() << "\n";    // some variant of "Foo"
std::cout << b << "\n";                   // "1"
std::cout << sizeof(b) << "\n";           // implementation-defined, not greater
                                          // than sizeof(int)
```

Comment: *"It is true that the type of your first enumerator is `char`"* only until the `}` of the enum, see my comment to the OP.

Comment: @dyp: Well, yes, the enumerator isn't something that's available to the program. It's only there as part of the definition of the enum type.

Comment: Huh? /11 says "Each *enum-name* and each unscoped *enumerator* is declared in the scope that immediately contains the
*enum-specifier*." As far as I can tell, these constants are *enumerators*, even if you access them after the end of the enumeration declaration. (and later in /11 "An enumerator declared in class scope can be referred to using the class member access
operators [...]")

Comment: @dyp: OK, you're right. I actually found a way to observe the type of the enumerator during definition, see edit.

Comment: See my comment to the OP ;)

Answer (score 4):

No.  It has been the case ever since ANSI C that conforming compilers often use `int` to store enums, even when all the values are small.

Before you say this is insane and it should use the smallest type that works (which by the way GCC will do if you use `__attribute__((packed))`), think about ABI compatibility.  If you release a library which uses an enum type, you would prefer that the size of that type not change.  If all enums start life with 4 bytes, the likelihood is increased that simply relinking against an updated library will work.

Comment: I wish language designers would allow programmers to specify types in terms of *requirements*.  If a type needs to hold values 0-50,000 and must be stored compactly, but wrapping behavior doesn't matter, on many processors it would be best for it to be a `uint16_t` when stored in memory memory but a `uint32_t` when kept in a register.  If something is needed which wraps mod 4,294,967,296 then it should wrap mod 4,294,967,296 regardless of the machine's native word size.  The better a language lets a programmer specify requirements, the fewer compromises will be needed for various usage cases.